# Change or denie Cursor Style change of requestFocus in Textfields

Tags: java

From my understanding, the requestFocus Method from the component class, does set the Cursor Style while hovering over a TextItem. (The One looking like an I)

The application i am working with, does run in two different modes. 
The first mode is the normal application mode, and the cursor is free to change.

The other on the help mode. It does contain a normal Cursor with a questionmark next to it.
In this mode the Cursor is not allowed to change when hovering over any textItem, since it wont create any input.

Is there any way to denie the Cursor change from happening, or to change the Default Cursor of  a textitem temporarly?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the Cursor of the TextField like this:

```
textField.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.CUSTOM_CURSOR));
```